# How to change date format in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is this normal that rails put something like this :

```
DateTime.now = 2013-07-28T16:21:13+02:00
```

Why this T is between date and time ? How can i remove it. In I18n i have default:

```
default: ! '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
```

Comment: If you have set the default in I18n, then use I18n to format the DateTime: `I18n.l(DateTime.now, format: :default)` (Yes, `format: :default` is optional unless you want another format than `:default`)

Comment: ok but why i see this T - i have other rails app and there is no T between date and time.

Comment: It is because the method `to_s` has been called to this date: doing `puts DateTime.now` calls an implicit `to_s` on `DateTime.now` (in your IRB console, try `DateTime.now` and `DateTime.now.to_s`, you will understand)

Answer (score 2):

In your IRB console, if you call `puts variable`, it will make an implicit call to the method `to_s` on the `variable` object:

```
1.9.3 > DateTime.now
# => Wed, 28 Aug 2013 10:39:30 -0400 
1.9.3 > puts DateTime.now
2013-08-28T10:39:33-04:00
# => nil 
1.9.3 > DateTime.now.to_s
# => "2013-08-28T10:39:37-04:00"
```

This is why you see a "T" in the output, its `.to_s`'s fault!